# AG-Grid Concat fields

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to concat multiple fields in AG Grid. This is working but when the field is blank the grid shows undefined.

See my code below. I have a grid that has a students First, Middle and Last Name. However, when the Middle name is blank, the 'Student' field, where the values are concatenated it shows the middle name as undefined.

```
this.state = {
      modules: AllCommunityModules,
      columnDefs: [
        {
          field:"FirstName",
          headerName: "FirstName",
        },

        {
          field: "MiddleName",
          header: "MiddleName",
        },

        {
          field: "LastName",
          header: "LastName",
        },

        {
          field: "Student",
          header: "Student",
          valueGetter: studentValueGetter,
        },
```

```
function studentValueGetter(params) {
  return params.data.FirstName + params.data.MiddleName + params.data.LastName;
}
```

| A header | Another header | A header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Pete | Smith | JohnPeteSmith |
| Sarah |  | Jane | SarahunderfinedJane |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a condition on the middle name:

```js
return params.data.FirstName + ' ' +
  (params.data.MiddleName ? params.data.MiddleName + ' ' : '') +
  params.data.LastName;
```

Or the same thing with more advanced syntax:

```js
const { FirstName, MiddleName, LastName } = params.data;
return [FirstName, MiddleName, LastName].filter(n => !!n).join(' ');
```

Not an ag-grid specific thing though; this is JavaScript generally.